# Customize TextView to look like Menu Item

Tags: android, material-design, menuitem

I am trying to specify my own Android Navigation Drawer.
There is dynamic data shown so I can't just set it up in a menu.xml. 
Right now I am trying to customize the look of a TextView into my ListView to look pretty much like a Menu Item but these classes are all abstract. Furthermore I was not able to find something usefull at the material.io.

What I am looking for:

[image]

What I got right now:

[image]

Here is the corresponding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".SlideshowActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_slide_show">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        tools:context=".SlideshowActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButtonRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
            android:alpha="0.5"  />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButtonLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager_slideshow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="5px"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/ic_media_pause_dark" >

        </ListView>


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: are you use ListView With Adapter?

Comment: Show your xml layout

Comment: @Radesh Yes I use an Adapter to draw the Paths you can see on the second Picture

Comment: @Bunny I've updated the entry

Answer (score 0):

You need to Customize the navigation drawer by using the listview with custom Adapter.Here is example of Custom [navigation drawer](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-custom-navigation-drawer-example/).